# Custom SoftKeyBoard in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, tamil, input-language

Does SoftKeyBoard support the Indian Languages(Hindi,Tamil,Telugu,etc) in Android? The packages [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) and [UnicodeBlock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) are used for the Fonts. But how to integrate the Custom IME in it? the [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) in the developer site is not enough.

Can you share some idea or tutorials?

Answer (score 3):

there is an IME named "[Tamil Visai](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tamil.visai&feature=search_result)" at app store. Check it out. It enables Tamil input in Android apps.

you can download the [Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-tamilkey/source/checkout) @ Google Code.

Hope it helps you.